# Swift3 - var variable warning in stride method

Tags: swift3

I have to generate a number based on a given start , end and step and insert it into an array , for eg , Start = 10 , end = 30 , step = 5 , then 
my array should be [10,15,20,25,30] , I am able to achieve this by the below method

```
for var index in stride(from: start, through: end, by: step) {
            self.myArray.append(self.getElement(number: index))
        }
```

But I keep getting a warning in xCode as variable index was never mutated , and if I change the var index to let index then I get a compilation error as "let pattern cannot appear nested in an already immutable context'.

Any idea how to suppress this warning in Swift 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete `var` entirely. `for index in...`